# Floating two elements to the right in a flexible container

Tags: css

I'm trying to float two elements (buttons) to the right of a flexible container.

One of the buttons is also flexible, as the text within it changes depending on who's logged into the system.

Any ideas how this can be achieved? Help is much appreciated! I've already tried float rights (the order of the buttons is wrong when I do that) and display: inline-block (doesn't work).

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Edit:

Code I've tried (that doesn't work). This is psuedo version, as I'm currently overhauling a pre-existing system -

```
<div style="width: 100%">
   <div style="float:right; text-align: right;">
       <input type="submit" style="display: inline-block"></button>
       <button style="display: inline-block"></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post your tried code

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath Updated the original post with my code snippet.

Comment: add `position:relative` to all elements

Comment: @johnSmith Didn't work I'm afraid, the two elements remained stacked on top of each other.

Comment: @LiamRichardson it works perfectly here..http://jsfiddle.net/hdjp21ms/  please tell the problem

Comment: so [something like this?](http://jsbin.com/cuquqe/2/edit?css,output)

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath Ah, my bad. There was another DIV element wrapped around the button element that needed to be set as `display: inline-block` as well. Once that was added, it all worked perfectly. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @LiamRichardson: can i add my suggestion as answer

Comment: @LiamRichardson: i have added my fiddle as an answer..so that you can accept the answer..!! :) :)

Comment: @LiamRichardson, not sure why you would need a float:rightdiv if your buttons are inline-block.  A simple text-align:right on the parent should suffice: http://jsfiddle.net/hdjp21ms/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works perfectly..please check your project code completely,

```
<div style="width: 100%">
   <div style="float:right; text-align: right;">
       <input type="submit" style="display: inline-block"/>
       <button style="display: inline-block">flexible</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

works perfectly here..
[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hdjp21ms/)